# How do I center my text in div tag I and why does it have a space between the words an and extremely?

Tags: html, css

How do I center my .peachtext and my .whitetext paragraph tags text within the .headertext1 div? Please help! I'm pretty new to coding. I'd also like to increase the .peachtext size to 30px and the .whitetext to about 20px but it produces a space between the words an and extremely. It seems like my text-align property is not working.

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1229px;
}
div.headerblue{
    width: 100%;
    height: 505px;
    background-color: #323841; 
}
div.headerwhite{
    width: 100%;
    height: 594px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.headerorange{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #f25c43; 
}
 div.headertext1 {
 width: 940px;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
     
}
p.peachtext {
 color: #f25c43;
 font-size: 20px;
 text-align: center;
    
}
p.whitetext {
    color:white;
    font-size: 10px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
                 <div class="headerblue"> 
                     <div class="headertext1">
                        <p class="peachtext">WE PROVIDE AN EXTREMELY</p>
                         <p class="whitetext">LOW PRICE</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="headerwhite"></div>
                 <div class="headerorange"></div>  
            </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center your `.peachtext` and, `.whitetext` inside your `div.headertext1`

you should set the width of your 
`.headertext1` from 940px to 100%

```
 div.headertext1 {
   width: 100%; //set this to 100%
   margin: auto;
   padding-top: 30px;
}
```

or you change the width to max-width if you want to keep 940px

```
 div.headertext1 {
       max-width: 940px; //set this to max-width
       margin: auto;
       padding-top: 30px;
    }
```

and if you want to adjust the font size of your text you may use "VW" instead of "PX"
like this

```
p.peachtext {
  color: #f25c43;
  font-size: 4vw;
  text-align: center;

}
p.whitetext {
  color:white;
  font-size: 2vw;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: For some reason setting the max-width at 940px or setting the width at 100% didn't work. Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: what is your desired output?
this is what i have tried https://jsfiddle.net/jvxn75eL/

Comment: I do want to keep .headertext1 at a width of 940px because I have a background that is the dark blue color that fills the whole browser but I need my content to be centered within that 940px at the center. I'm using the 960 grid, 12 column layout, for reference. I actually have several other background colors for the header that take up the full width of the browser. Should I post my entire code? I'm not sure of the etiquette is of this site.

Comment: you can post it via jsfiddle, so I may try to help you out.

Comment: It looks very similar but I have an image that I am inserting into a div that will cover a portion of the .headerwhite tag. So then I'm positioning my .headerwhite tag as relative and then the div#headerimage tag (that has the image in it) as absolute. If I post my code on jsfiddle then I know my images won't show. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Ran snippet on Firefox and the placements are exactly like you want them to be, both paragraphs nicely in the center of the div. Just increase your font-sizes to get the sizes you want. You sure your css file is correctly linked ?

Comment: You're very right, it is working when that bit of code is isolated, but it's still not working in my file and my CSS file is linked. I actually only posted a snipped of my code for the header section so it's got to be because of some other function in another part of my file. I feel like if I posted all my code it might be too much. I'm not sure what the etiquette is for this site as I've never posted before. Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 0):

```css
header{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1229px;
}
div.headerblue{
    width: 100%;
    height: 505px;
    background-color: #323841;
}
div.headerwhite{
    width: 100%;
    height: 594px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
div.headerorange{
    width: 100%;
    height: 130px;
    background-color: #f25c43; 
}
 div.headertext1 {
 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding-top: 30px;
     
}
p.peachtext {
 color: #f25c43;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
    
}
p.whitetext {
    color:white;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
                 <div class="headerblue"> 
                     <div class="headertext1">
                        <p class="peachtext">WE PROVIDE AN EXTREMELY</p>
                         <p class="whitetext">LOW PRICE</p>
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <div class="headerwhite"></div>
                 <div class="headerorange"></div>  
            </header>
```

Check the above code.